# Is there any alternate method for SetFocusOnLoad method in the latest AjaxControlToolkit?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Recently I have upgraded AjaxControlToolkit from version 4.x to 15.1. In the older version, I could use the following code to set focus.

```
protected void SetFocus( System.Web.UI.Control ctrl )
    {
        AjaxControlToolkit.Utility.SetFocusOnLoad(ctrl);

    }
```

But in the latest version, I couldn't find such a method. I have checked on the codeplex page at https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/  for any alternate method, but couldn't find any details.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, this code was removed in the latest v15.1.

However, you can easily add it in your project, here is the code:

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Set the focus of a control after all the client-side behaviors
    /// have finished initializing
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="control">Control to focus</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// SetFocusOnLoad is a replacement for ScriptManager.SetFocus and
    /// Page.SetFocus that will focus the control after any client-side
    /// behaviors have been initialized.
    /// </remarks>
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Globalization", "CA1303:DoNotPassLiteralsAsLocalizedParameters", Justification = "Assembly is not localized")]
    public static void SetFocusOnLoad(Control control)
    {
        if (control == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("control", "Control cannot be null!");
        }

        string script =
            "(function() { " +
                "var fn = function() { " +
                    "var control = $get('" + control.ClientID + "'); " +
                    "if (control && control.focus) { control.focus(); } " +
                    "Sys.Application.remove_load(fn);" +
                "};" +
                "Sys.Application.add_load(fn);" +
            "})();";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(control.Page, control.GetType(),
            control.ClientID + "_SetFocusOnLoad", script, true);
    }
```